# Regular expression missing the pattern match

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to match a pattern with my input using regular expression .
I am trying to match the following string

```
00010_mesh_fbx_low_pileOfStoneAtWonwonsaTemple.fbx
```

using the following regular expression

```
std::regex("^[0-9]+_mesh_fbx_low_[a-z][A-Z][0-9].(?:fbx|glb|obj)"))
```

But I do not get a match for the input string

Comment: You need `std::regex(R"(^[0-9]+_mesh_fbx_low_\w+\.(?:fbx|glb|obj))")`, see https://regex101.com/r/uj72IU/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-z][A-Z][0-9].` matches a sequence of four chars: a lowercase ASCII letter, then an uppercase ASCII letter, then an ASCII digit and then any char other than line break chars.

You can fix your regex by using

```cpp
std::regex(R"(^[0-9]+_mesh_fbx_low_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:fbx|glb|obj))")
std::regex(R"(^[0-9]+_mesh_fbx_low_\w+\.(?:fbx|glb|obj))")
```

where `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches one or more ASCII alphanumeric chars, or `\w+` that matches one or more ASCII alphanumeric or underscore chars.